Warping a set of points to fit another set of points
I have a set of approximately sinusoidal points from -1 to 1 in the XY plane. I need to "map" these points to an arbitrary curve defined by another set of points, so that one could see that this is the same curve now somewhere else in the XY plane. How can I do this?

Compute the optimal transport plan, it should give you a smooth map between the two sets of points. You can use POT to precompute this.

"this is the same curve now somewhere else in the XY plane": what???
